# Tiles Expression Language

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I'm using Spring MVC 3 with Tiles 3.
I return something like 'MIS/Home' from controller which is handled by following definition:

```
    <definition name="*/*" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/{1}/{2}.jsp" />
    </definition>
```

Now I want to return something like 'MIS/XYZ/Home' for which I had to write something like

```
    <definition name="*/*/*" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/{1}/{2}/{3}.jsp" />
    </definition>
```

Now after writing that the previous one stops working and throws error. I'm unable to have both of them together. Or is there some direct method??

Answer (score 0):

Are you finding that the second definition is catching everything?

Maybe you need to go from WILDCARD to REGEXP so to avoid the overlap…
 http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/wildcard.html